# Should I pip install python inside virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.6, python-install

I need python3.6 for tensorflow installation, so I downloaded python3.6.12.tar. And I found that I should pip install tarfile. However, in this case it is an older version of python. FYI, In my computer(laptop) I installed python3.9.
My question is: can I pip install python.tar inside a virtualenv?

Comment: No, you cannot install Python with `pip`.

Comment: I'm trying to "setup.py install" right now but it gives me some kind of error...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blahblahblah\Python36\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    set_compiler_flags('CFLAGS', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST')
  File "blahblahblah\Python36\setup.py", line 27, in set_compiler_flags
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()[compiler_flags] = flags + ' ' + py_flags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython#build-instructions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+build+python+from+sources

Comment: Yes I can install another version of python now. ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how virtual environments work. I suggest you to do a little bit more research on virtual environments in Python.

[Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Basically you need to install the necessary python version onto your machine. Then go ahead and use that specific python (which is version 3.6 in your case), to create a virtual environment with the command

`~ /usr/bin/<path-to-python3.6> -m venv venv`

This command will create a folder called *venv*. Now you need to source the activation script inside this folder to activate your environment.

---

Handy note: if you are dealing with different versions of python, a more robust way of handling such situations is via using a tool called [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).